# Problema al enviar consulta a base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

tengo un formulario, pero para enviarlo se verifica que esa información no este en la base de datos, el problema es que este o no este en la base de datos devuelve el mensaje de que ya está guardado. ¿Como puedo solucionarlo?

```
    $dni = $_POST['dni'];
    $nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
    $licencia = rand(100,500);

    $conn = mysqli_connect("a", "a", "a", "a");
    $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM votantes WHERE dni= '$dni'") or die ("Error: $sql1");

    $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1);

    if($mostrar['dni'] !== ''){
    echo "<script>
                alert('ERROR: Su dni ya esta registrado.\\n\\nSi no puede votar o tiene algún problema mandenos un correo a: incidencias@clubasirio.com');
                window.location= 'licencia.php'
    </script>";
    }else{
        mysqli_query($conn,"
        INSERT INTO votantes (nombre ,dni ,licencia)
        VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$dni."', '".$licenica."')");
    echo "<script>
                alert('CLAVE: '".$licenica."' (Introducir esta clave en el campo -licencia-)\\n\\nSi tiene algún problema mandenos un correo a: incidencias@clubasirio.com');
                window.location= 'votacion.php#section-contact'
    </script>";

    }
```

Comment: El primer paso es que depures los datos con los que estás trabajando. Si la validación no funciona como esperas, entonces haz un `var_dump($mostrar['dni']);` y dinos lo que muestra. También puedes depurar todos los resultados que arroja la consulta haciendo un `var_dump($mostrar);` Aunque lo más certero aquí sería hacer una consulta con `COUNT(*)` y determinar la cantidad de registros que arrojó.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar la constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` en tu función `mysql_fetch_array()`, quedando de la siguiente manera:

```php
$mostrar = mysqli_fetch_array($sql1, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```

También considero que si solo validaras un campo en la consulta, la limites a ese campo, es decir:

```php
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT dni FROM votantes WHERE dni= '$dni'") or die ("Error: $sql1");
```

Y en tu condición para saber si existe, podrías checar la longitud de la cadena:

```php
if(strlen($mostrar['dni'] > 0){

  //código aquí

}
```

Espero que sea de utilidad.

Saludos

Comment: Con esto lo he solucionado pero no se me muestra la varieble $licencia, simplemente no se me muestra el mensaje, ¿Que puede estar mal?

Comment: Podria ser el nombre de la variable ya que la tienes declarada como $licencia e intentas mostrarla como $licenica.

Answer (score 2):

Concuerdo con @A.Cedano en que es preferible contar, porque siempre te devuelve un registro. Como lo tienes ahora, en caso de no encontrar coincidencia, lo más seguro es que $mostrar sea un valor nulo (o variable indefinida) y la comparación por valor y tipo **!==** va a resultar verdadera.

```
$dni = $_POST['dni'];
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$licencia = rand(100,500);

$conn = mysqli_connect("a", "a", "a", "a");

// COUNT(*) en lugar de seleccionar todos los campos
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM votantes WHERE dni= '$dni'") or die ("Error: $sql1");
// Devuelve array con índice numérico
$contar = mysqli_fetch_row($sql1);

// La consulta solicita solo un campo, por eso el índice es cero
if($contar[0] > 0){
    // Se encontró al menos un registro
    echo "<script>
            alert('ERROR: Su dni ya esta registrado.\\n\\nSi no puede votar o tiene algún problema mandenos un correo a: incidencias@clubasirio.com');
            window.location= 'licencia.php'
    </script>";
}else{
    mysqli_query($conn,"
    INSERT INTO votantes (nombre ,dni ,licencia)
    VALUES ('".$nombre."', '".$dni."', '".$licenica."')");
echo "<script>
            alert('CLAVE: '".$licenica."' (Introducir esta clave en el campo -licencia-)\\n\\nSi tiene algún problema mandenos un correo a: incidencias@clubasirio.com');
            window.location= 'votacion.php#section-contact'
</script>";

}
```

Por cierto, tu script es vulnerable porque no estás realizando validaciones ni escapando los datos antes de incluirlos en una consulta. Te sugiero usar sentencias preparadas: https://www.php.net/manual/es/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php